# Saving Sales order in user custom tables Dynamic AX

Tags: dynamic, axapta

I want to save the Sales Order in Dynamic Ax 2012 in user defined table. I had googled alot on the internet but didnot find anything relevant to this. Can anybody please let me know that How i could obtain that result saving in the custom Table. And after that Copied that record if the sales order workflow is run successfully.

Please Help.

Comment: @DieterMeemken I am making the changes in the sales order and try to use the custom tables (User defined Tables) to hold the data and when the workflow is completed and the order is placed then I want to move the result back to the original tables. Hope you understand this.

Comment: If I understand you well, you need to create new tables and forms to run your specific workflow and at the end copy data to the standard tables.